# I want to know if it is possible to loop through an array of object containing arrays to find an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, postman

Is it possible to loop through an array of objects containing arrays to find a particular array. So in other words, I already have a variable a which has the value "60749428", so I am trying to say find a which is "60749428" in the "available" array.This is the code sample below:

```
    "values": {
            "available": [
                {
                    "60750276": [
                        {
                            "count": 11,
                            "name": "16",
                            "percentage": 84.6153846153846,
                            "value": "16"
                        },
                        {
                            "count": 11,
                            "name": "16.0.1",
                            "percentage": 84.6153846153846,
                            "value": "16.0.1"
                        },
                        {
                            "count": 12,
                            "name": "16.2",
                            "percentage": 92.3076923076923,
                            "value": "16.2"
                        },
                        {
                            "count": 7,
                            "name": "16.2.4",
                            "percentage": 53.8461538461538,
                            "value": "16.2.4"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "69127027": [
                        {
                            "count": 8,
                            "name": "65",
                            "percentage": null,
                            "value": "65"
                        },
                        {
                            "count": 4,
                            "name": "69",
                            "percentage": null,
                            "value": "69"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "60749428": [
                        {
                            "count": 8,
                            "name": "How To",
                            "percentage": 61.5384615384615,
                            "value": "How To"
                        },
                        {
                            "count": 4,
                            "name": "Training",
                            "percentage": 30.7692307692308,
                            "value": "Training"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Comment: It _must_ be possible since this question is asked and answered about 100 times per day ;)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code sample, it looks like you can use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to achieve this

```js
let values = {            "available": [                {                    "60750276": [                        {                            "count": 11,                            "name": "16",                            "percentage": 84.6153846153846,                            "value": "16"                        },                        {                            "count": 11,                            "name": "16.0.1",                            "percentage": 84.6153846153846,                            "value": "16.0.1"                        },                        {                            "count": 12,                            "name": "16.2",                            "percentage": 92.3076923076923,                            "value": "16.2"                        },                        {                            "count": 7,                            "name": "16.2.4",                            "percentage": 53.8461538461538,                            "value": "16.2.4"                        }                    ]                },                {                    "69127027": [                        {                            "count": 8,                            "name": "65",                            "percentage": null,                            "value": "65"                        },                        {                            "count": 4,                            "name": "69",                            "percentage": null,                            "value": "69"                        }                    ]                },                {                    "60749428": [                        {                            "count": 8,                            "name": "How To",                            "percentage": 61.5384615384615,                            "value": "How To"                        },                        {                            "count": 4,                            "name": "Training",                            "percentage": 30.7692307692308,                            "value": "Training"                        }                    ]                }            ]        }
        
let res = values.available.find(d => d[60749428])

console.log(res)
```

Comment: thanks Nitish, this works but d isnt initialized, how does it still work. Sorry I am new to this

Comment: No problem. This would be the good starting point for you. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find